# Forcefully stop and close Active Session

Tags: ios, facebook, session

I'm using latest FBSDK v4.3 which is using Login Version v2.3.

I need to stop and close the current Active Session but I couldn't be able to find out FBSession Class and its corresponding methods.

Can anyone please help me out to get rid of this issue so that when user taps on Facebook provided Logout button then I can stop and close current Active Session.

I tried below code but its throwing me error like 'Unknown type name 'FBSession'.

```
FBSession *session = [session activeSession];
[session closeAndClearTokenInformation];
[session close];
[FBSession setActiveSession:nil];
```

Please hep me out. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

In v4.x of the Facebook SDK you can use the new `FBSDKLoginManager` class and call the `logOut` method which would have the same effect.

In the background it simply calls `[FBSDKAccessToken setCurrentAccessToken:nil]` to remove the access token and also resets the Facebook profile cached in `FBSDKProfile`